# How to stop capture session when it is inside the Collection View Cell in iOS , Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I have implemented a QR Reader using (AVFoundation) AVCapture Session in iOS. In my **ParentViewController** I have implemented a **CollectionView**. inside the **collection view cell** I have implemented **QR Code Reader** and I start the capture session start running inside the cell. it works fine and read the metadata output. I stop the session when metadata output delegates called. But If I leave the ParentView Controller the Capture Session is still running and when I navigate to another ViewController it capture the session from background. Why is this and how can I stop the capture session When navigating to another view controller.

**Here is the Hierarchy,**

```
ParentViewController --->(inside)CollectionView --->(inside) CollectionViewCell --->(inside) QR Reader with capture session Strat.
```

**What Happens,**

```
ParentViewController ----> (navigate to another controller) Capture Session Still Activated and reads qr codes from background
```

**What I want,**

```
ParentViewController ---->(navigate to another controller) Shouldn't capture anything.
```

**I Tried In ParentViewController, inside viewWillDisappear**

```
    override open func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

         let qrreaderCell = QRReaderCell()
         qrreaderCell.captureSession.stopRunning()
         ColletionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)])
        }
```

but didn't work and failed. can anyone help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating new instance of `QRReaderCell`.

```
let qrreaderCell = QRReaderCell()
qrreaderCell.captureSession.stopRunning()
```

Instead of creating new instance, just access the current cell which contains the QRReader.

```
let qrreaderCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))
qrreaderCell.captureSession.stopRunning()
```

And make sure your `viewWillDisappear` get called. and if not, you can stop the capture session right before you navigate to another viewController.
just stop the capture session right before you push or segue to another viewController.

Answer (score 0):

It seems more likely there is a retain cycle, but tough to tell without seeing your cell configuration code.

To stop existing sessions, you should iterate your collection view and stop the session on any already existing cells. You could do this in viewDidDisappear (your approach created a new cell, which would be released anyways at the end of the method)

If you post the cell class and the controller class code perhaps it may be helpful.